# wpf password box into a SecureString in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to get the data from a wpf password box into a secure string.  How is that done?
what i have so far:

```
 SecureString pass = new SecureString();
        pass.AppendChar(pbox1.Password);
```

this of course does not work, so how would I get the password data without creating a regular string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to read each character in

```
SecureString pass = new SecureString();

foreach (char c in pbox1.Password)
{
  pass.AppendChar(c);
}
```

or more securely use the SecurePassword property

```
SecureString pass = pbox1.SecurePassword
```

Comment: Doing this pretty much defeats the purpose of using `SecureString`.

Answer (score 18):

[Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.password.aspx):

> When you get the Password property
>   value, you expose the password as
>   plain text in memory. To avoid this
>   potential security risk, use the
>   SecurePassword property to get the
>   password as a SecureString.

You should avoid using the Password property unless you absolutely need a plaintext version of the string. In this case, retrieve the SecureString directly.

Comment: If only there were a way to set the password using SecureString

Answer (score 3):

```
SecureString pass = pbox1.SecurePassword.Copy();
```