# Windows credentials prompt in custom WPF dialog

Tags: wpf, winforms, windows-7, credential-providers

***Q.** How can I reuse in WPF the security features provided by the [Windows credentials dialog](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4693/using-the-credential-management-api/) (WinForms32)?*

**Brainstorm (not sure if any of these are possible):**

1. Host the WinForms32 dialog inside my own WPF dialog. MSDN has an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx) that explains how to host a WinForms **control** (i.e., textbox, etc.) but not a WinForms dialog. Yes, this will be ugly, but we're not worried about looks right now.
2. Provide a WPF GUI that wraps the WinForms dialog. Upon login, the WPF username textbox and WPF [`SecurePassword`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978348/wpf-password-box-into-a-securestring-in-c-sharp) textbox are transferred to their WinForms equivalent under the covers. The moving of sensitive data might pose a security risk (but some may argue that the attacker has plenty of other ways to steal your password).
3. Move the WinForms username and password textboxes to the WPF dialog ("re-parent" the existing textboxes).

Any suggestions/comments (including criticism of my ideas) are appreciated!

Comment: i usually don't ask why, but with security i must... Why? (isn't the user already logged in?)

Comment: No, not necessarily. The login domain for this application isn't necessarily the same as the one used to log into Windows. The application allows switching the authentication server.

Comment: the `Windows credentials dialog` article that you linked to shows all of the background code. why can't you just plop it into a custom `Window`?

Comment: That article doesn't indicate how to "plop it into a custom window". I wish it were that simple.

Comment: lolz, sorry for that. they have all the needed pinvoke functions there. create a custom WPF window with the user, password, etc controls and pinvoke on OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just show WinForms dialog in WPF application the same way you do it in regular WinForms application and it just works. For example WPF does not have FolderBrowserDialog but we use WinForms version of this dialog and it works ok.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to avoid popping up a dialog that has a different look from the rest of the application.

Comment: I decided to just let the dialog show on its own instead of embedding it.