# PasswordBox binding in MVVM

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm, passwords

A problem with binding to a PasswordBox, it's a security risk but I am using the MVVM pattern I found some interesting code here

http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html

I basically have properties in my LoginViewModel for Username and Password. Username is fine and is working as it's a TextBox.

I used the code above as stated and entered this

```
<PasswordBox ff:PasswordHelper.Attach="True"
ff:PasswordHelper.Password="{Binding Path=Password}" Width="130"/>
```

When I had the PasswordBox as a TextBox and Binding Path=Password then the property in my LoginViewModel was updated.

My code is very simple, basically I have a Command for my Button. When I press it CanLogin is called and if it returns true it calls Login.
You can see I check my property for Username here which works great.

In Login I send along to my service a Username and Password, Username contains data from my View but Password is Null|Empty

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     MinWidth="180" />

<PasswordBox ff:PasswordHelper.Attach="True" 
         ff:PasswordHelper.Password="{Binding Path=Password}" Width="130"/>
```

I have my TextBox, this is no problem, but in my ViewModel the Password is empty.

I put a breakpoint and sure enough the code enter the static helper class but it never updates my Password in my ViewModel

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind to a PasswordBox in MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using SecureString as recommended by MSDN, see references here:

[wpf password box into a SecureString in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978348/wpf-password-box-into-a-securestring-in-c-sharp)

Let me know if that helps out, we have successfully bound passwords via attached properties but hoping you can learn from the above links for yourself :)

Comment: On the verge of a down vote here... I'd remove that first link if I were you, because *it has no answer* and it shows that *you didn't bother to check before adding your link*.

Answer (score 0):

Please stop what you are trying to do, as passing unencrypted passwords around an application is a terrible security risk. You should be logging in your users like this:

Provide Username and Password input fields for them as you have, but the value for the password should be encrypted immediately. Your database should store these *encrypted passwords only*. So to verify whether a user has entered the correct password or not, you simply compare the values of *the encrypted passwords*.

Therefore, you don't need to pass the value of the user password field to the database to check it... you need to pass the *encrypted* password value from the database *to* the view model.